# Magento redirect to login page after successful login

Tags: magento, mamp

I have made a copy of a website on my local machine so I can work on an offline version.

After logging in, I am redirected back to the login page. I know I have logged in as if I type in a wrong password I get "Invalid User Name or Password." message.

I have double checked the cookies path in the database, this is empty.
I have also tried adding a . in the config file but I'm not able to connect when I update the url to 127.0.0.1.

Is there anything I can check/try?

I am using mamp...

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/customer-cant-log-in-redirect-to-login-page

Answer (score 0):

Try changing address from http://localhost to something with more than one domain component. Sometimes there are  issues with logging in using domain without single dot. http://magento.localhost may work in this case.

Comment: I have updated the url in the database from http://localhost:8888/website to http://magento.localhost/website. Do I need to update host in the config file? its not allowing me to connect this way. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have a vhost for Magento in MAMP config make sure it has `magento.localhost` in `ServerName` / `ServerAlias` directive. Additionaly `magento.localhost` domain needs to point to `127.0.0.1`, if not update your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: it's not connecting at all now. I updated the hosts and vhosts files. The config file host is "magento.localhost". http://magento.localhost/website/ loads with an unable to connect error

Comment: Could you attach your vhost file? Did you restart MAMP and browser after changes? You've mentioned port `8888` earlier, you should still use it if you didn't change it: http://magento.localhost:8888/website .

Comment: The website is working now http://magento.localhost:8888/website but still the same issue with the redirect to the login page after logging in...

Comment: Is the session cookie properly created? Please look at this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26083

Comment: I couldn't get it working on my local machine but its working on a server however the menu bar isn't working! I'm comparing the source code and there are a lot of additional js files on the duplicate site and none on the live site (admin dashboard page) prototype.js is coming up with a lot of errors in the console. prototype.js file isn't even included on the live site. I have put dev/js/merge_files to 0 but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't think of simple solution for more assets on duplicated production site but switching `dev/js/merge_files` to `1`, it is hard to say what could go wrong. Disable all caches and check if urls to assets are valid. That's for start. Also it is impossible to replace `prototype.js` in Magento 1 so probably `prototype.js` is included in one of merged js files on live site.